# Exodus 12:24 HaDavar Hazeh?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, bo

[Shemot/Exodus 12:24](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9873/jewish/Chapter-12.htm#v=24) quotes the following words: ושמרתם את הדבר הזה לחק לך ולבניך עד עולם - Translated something like: You shall observe this thing (word/matter) as an institution/ordinance for you and for your descendants for all time..

What I would like to know is what the words את הדבר הזה - Et HaDavar Hazeh - this thing/word/matter is refering to: to the putting of the blood on the lintel and doorposts, the korban Pesach, or keeping the celebration of Chag HaPesach (the meal, with it's teachings for the children), or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Midrash Lekah Tov states that this refers to the paschal offering; specifically, that it be a sheep or a goat:

> ושמרתם את הדבר הזה. להביא פסח דורות, שלא יביא אלא מן הכבשים ומן העזים
>
> And you shall safeguard this thing: This includes all offerings of the *Pesah* in the future; that one must bring them from sheep and goats.

[Ibn Ezra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_ibn_Ezra) too explains (in his extended commentary to the verse) that it refers to the offering of the paschal lamb; not to putting blood on the doorposts:

> ושמרתם רבים חשבו, כי נתינת הדם על המשקוף ועל שתי המזוזות חיוב לדורות...ובדרך הסברא נכון היה לולי קבלת האמת הנגמרת הנה הנכון שמלת הדבר הזה שב אל ושחטו הפסח.
>
> And you shall safeguard: Many have thought that placing the blood on the lintel and two doorposts is a permanent obligation, and this would have been reasonable if not for the received truth. The correct understanding is that the term 'this thing' refers back to 'And you shall slaughter the Pesah'.

Although Ibn Ezra understands that "this thing" in verse 24, refers specifically to the slaughtering of the *Pesah*, he nevertheless explains that that when the next verse says that you will come to the land and safeguard 'this service', and the subsequent verse (26) states that your children will ask 'what is this service to you', that the question about 'this service' which is apparently identical to 'this thing', is not not just why an animal is being offered, or why a particular species is being offered, but rather the question includes the entire experience of slaughtering and consuming the offering, including that the the whole family joins together to consume it, that it is (roasted and) consumed whole, without breaking bones, etc.

> וטעם שאלת הבנים בראותם כל המשפחה חבורה אחת אוכלים שה תמים ראשו על כרעיו ועל קרבו, ועצם לא תשברו בו, ובן נכר ותושב וערל ושכיר לא יאכל בו. ואין זה המנהג במועדים אחרים

Accordingly, although 'this thing' refers specifically to the slaughter, 'this service' mentioned immediately after, includes the various details of the offering and its consumption.

[Ramban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nahmanides) too (ibid) [states that](http://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.12.24?lang=bi&p2=Ramban_on_Exodus.12.28&lang2=en) "this thing" refers to the offering of the paschal lamb.

Comment: One more thing: does HaDavar Hazeh which is singular always refer to singular things?

Comment: @Levi It seems like it. the terms דבר and זה; 'thing' and 'this', are both in the single tense; no the plural. Every other time that such a term appears in the Bible, that I have noticed, can be referring to a specific thing: Genesis (18:25), (19:21), (20:10), (21:26), and Exodus (2:15). Exodus (24:9) is a bit different in that Eliezer swears to uphold 'this thing', which refers to the oath which has multiple components regarding finding a wife for Isaac: Not to choose a Canaanite wife, but to choose a wife from Abraham's relatives, and not to take Isaac to Canaan. (Plus that if the [cont.]

Comment: woman doesn't want to come, that he is absolved from his oath.) All of this is apparently included in 
וַיִּשָּׁ֣בַֽע ל֔וֹ עַל־הַדָּבָ֖ר הַזֶּֽה "and he swore to him on this thing".

Comment: @mevaqesh I know this question was asked a long time ago, but I wondered if you could help me out. If 'this thing' refers to the sacrafice, the offering of the Pesach lamb, does this mean this service also refers to the offering (in the Temple where 'avodah' was done on a regular basis)? If so, without the Temple, and without the offerings are uncircumcised people allowed then to join the celebration on Pesach Eve?